# Python 3 Index out of range error

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code executing in a postgresql server.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = str(datetime.now(None))
procurementinsertqueries=[]
priceupdatequeries = []
inventoryupdatequeries=[]
ptrcode = -1
debugcode=""

try:
    unpbatches=[]
    query = "select distinct(fk_procurementbatch_code) from newprocurementlist"
    proclistresult = plpy.execute(query)

    for rec in proclistresult:
        unpbatches.append(rec["fk_procurementbatch_code"])

    for batchcode in unpbatches:
        ptrcode=-1
        query = "select procurementtransaction_code from procurement where fk_procurementbatch_code="+str(batchcode)+" order by procurementtransaction_code desc limit 1"
        ptrcoderesult = plpy.execute(query)

        if len(ptrcoderesult)==0:
            ptrcode=0
        else:
            ptrcode=ptrcoderesult[0]["procurementtransaction_code"]

        query = "select * from newprocurementlist where fk_procurementbatch_code="+str(batchcode)
        newproclistresult = plpy.execute(query)

        for r in newproclistresult: 
            ptrcode+=1
            _bcode = str(r["fk_procurementbatch_code"])
            _pref = str(r["fk_product_ref"])
            _up = str(r["unitsprocured"])
            _tp = str(r["totalprice"])
            _cp = str(r["costprice"])
            _sp = str(r["sellingprice"])
            _mrp = str(r["mrp"])
            _trcode = str(ptrcode)
            procurementinsertqueries.append("insert into procurement values("+_bcode+","+_pref+","+_up+","+_tp+","+_cp+","+_sp+","+_mrp+","+_trcode+")")
            priceupdatequeries.append("insert into productpriceupdatelist values("+_pref+")")
            _aunits = 0.0
            _newunits = 0.0
            query="select unitsavailable from inventory where fk_product_ref="+_pref
            au = -1
            au = plpy.execute(query)
            _aunits=float(au[0]["unitsavailable"])
            _newunits = _aunits+float(r["unitsprocured"])
            inventoryupdatequeries.append("update inventory set unitsavailable="+str(_newunits)+" where fk_product_ref="+_pref)
            debugcode+="--Completed--"
        debugcode+="---Loop completed---"   

except Exception as e:
    plpy.execute("insert into log values(\'"+now+"\')")
    raise plpy.error("Error generating insert queries-->"+str(e)+"Debug is "+debugcode)

try:
    with plpy.subtransaction():
        for qry in procurementinsertqueries:
            plpy.execute(qry)
        for qry in priceupdatequeries:
            plpy.execute(qry)   
        for qry in inventoryupdatequeries:
            plpy.execute(qry)
except Exception as e:
    plpy.execute("insert into log values(\'"+now+": Error executing insert queries\')")
    raise plpy.error("Error executing procurement updates. There could be loss of data.Please review database error log. -->"+str(e))

try:
    plpy.execute("delete from newprocurementlist")
except Exception as e:
    plpy.execute("insert into log values(\'"+now+": Error deleting new procurement list table after successful updates\')")
    raise plpy.error("Error deleting completed procurement list. There could be duplication of data. Review error log file-->"+str(e))

try:
    plpy.execute("select product_price_update_process()")
except Exception as e:
    raise plpy.error("Error updating prices. "+str(e))
```

The problem is that I am getting an "index out of range" error. Attached is the erro I am getting.

```
ERROR:  plpy.Error: Error generating insert queries-->list index out of rangeDebug is --Completed--
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "procurementlist_process", line 61, in <module>
    raise plpy.error("Error generating insert queries-->"+str(e)+"Debug is "+debugcode)
PL/Python function "procurementlist_process"
```

I am not able to understand how the index is out of range when I am using a for loop.

Please help !!

EDIT : Note that the test data in  my table, the number of items in unpbatches is only 1.

Comment: You're swallowing the original exception. For testing purposes, reraise it in your except statement so we can see which lne it's actually coming from.

Comment: The exception is coming at the point where I am updating the queries lists. The control is not even going to the part where the queries are being executed. The error is popping up where I am inserting the queries to the appropriate lists.

Comment: You really need to just call `raise` by itself in the `except` clause so we can see the actual traceback and line numbers.

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: When I use "raise plpy.error(e)" i get this.-->ERROR:  plpy.Error: list index out of range
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "procurementlist_process", line 64, in <module>
    raise plpy.error(e)
PL/Python function "procurementlist_process"

Comment: Line 64 is the line where the exception is being processed.

Comment: This doesn't help as we can't see line numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `au` is an empty list here:

```
    au = plpy.execute(query)
    _aunits=float(au[0]["unitsavailable"])
```

Is `au` the result set of the query? Maybe the query did not return any rows.

---

More generally speaking, you should follow jknupp's suggestion in the comments and change

```
raise plpy.error("Error generating insert queries-->"+str(e)+"Debug is "+debugcode)
```

to just

```
raise
```

to see the original traceback and the exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: Checked it. Here is the error with a trace of _aunits. --plpy.Error: Error generating insert queries-->list index out of rangeDebug is _aunits = :1300.0--Completed----

Comment: The code is completing till the first iteration of the main for loop. Note that the number of batchcodes is only 1 in my test data. Does it make any difference??

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `ptrcode` to 1 if its length is 0, then immediately updating it when you enter the loop. Perhaps you meant to set it to `0`?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That is a mistake on my part. However, the ptrcode is just a column in a table and I've checked it with 0 as well, the error persists. It's value is not the cause of the error.